# React CSS module not working on certain selectors

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, module, selector

I'm learning the React as beginner. I'm working with CSS modules.

Menu.module.css is not 100% working, it's not applying styles for **.menu a.last** selector and I don't realize why (it's perfectly working for **.menu a**). The problem persist by using CSS modules, but it works as intended with plain CSS.

*Menu.jsx*

```
import styles from './Menu.module.css'

export default function Menu({ className, items = [], children }) {
    return (
    <div className={`menu ${styles.menu} ${className || ''}`}>
      {children ? <h2>{children}</h2> : ''}
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <a
              href={item.href}
              className={item.className || ''}
            >
              {item.name}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

*Menu.module.css*

```
.menu a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a.last {
  background: red !important;
}
```

Image of the code and HTML: https://ibb.co/r5m6W7s

I can get the **a.last** element through the console using the same querySelector as the CSS file is using so this leads me to think that there is a logical problem or CSS Modules selectors works differently than CSS this time.

I suppose it's a very easy to solve problem but can't get it. Thank you for your help.

Switched back to plain CSS to check if it would work and yes, it did work.

Tried to do it again from scratch with CSS Modules but it resulted in the same problem.

Tried changing class names even using plain class (not randomly generated by the CSS Modules compiler) and used this plain class name to check and it didn't work while still working with the .module.css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you should use `className={styles[item.className] || ''}`.

`item.className` will not refer to CSS module.

Comment: Hi, the CSS module class name is correctly applied you can check it on the image, forget about className argument, the CSS is not pointed to that selector but to the styles.menu selector which is defined in the CSS file and is also called in the div className property, thx

Comment: When you use CSS modules, all class names inside it will be given **new names**, to be sure they're scoped to that component only. Your `<a>` tag will receive the `.last` class you pass through the `items` *prop*, but as you're using CSS modules, there will NOT BE anymore a `.menu a.last {}` CSS rule, as the module will transform it into `.menu_something_Random a.last_somethingElse_Random`. So, if you don't have a normal, plain CSS rule for that, your tag will not be styled. The alternative I suggested in the answer is to pass also `.last` as a CSS module class.

Comment: OMG I got it. Didn't consider ALL class names changed while using CSS modules so I was just using .menu class correctly but wasn't using the .last class with the CSS modules proper selector/property, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by [cheesyMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15121332/cheesyman): I didn't consider ALL class names in the CSS file changed their names after using CSS modules. I was just using .menu CSS module selector but not the .last CSS module selector/property. The code was running like **.menu_random123 a.last** (wrong) while in order to work it needed **.menu_random123 a.last_random123**. It was so hard to notice because the **.last** class was being passed by the parent element.